# Upload image from iOS app to google app engine and bucket storage PHP

Tags: php, ios, google-app-engine, upload, content-type

I'm trying to upload an image sent from my iOS app to my bucket storage for app engine and I'm using php. Now let me be clear the example google gave with the web form works perfectly with my handler and it is commented out below So I'm sure my handler is fine and dandy also it works directly with my handler before using app engine and the storage bucket. For anyone unfamiliar with createUploadUrl [Here is the documentation on it](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/user_upload).

```css
<?php 
require_once 'google/appengine/api/cloud_storage/CloudStorageTools.php';

use google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;

$options = [ 'gs_bucket_name' => 'my-bucket-name' ];

$upload_url = CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl('/CustomPostHandler.php', $options);

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: multipart'
        )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents($upload_url,false,$context);

echo $result;
/*<form action="<?php echo $upload_url?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    Files to upload: <br>
   <input type="file" name="userfile" size="10000000">
   <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>*/

?>
```

Because i want to use storage bucket i call the createUploadUrl because thats what google wants. I'm using swift on the iOS front end and the error code I'm getting for echoing the $result is "The request's content type is not accepted on this url" I have tried to use 'multipart/form-data' for the php part and it gave me the error 'Bad type use multipart' or something along those lines.

the iOS code is posted below and again ill say this works perfectly when not running on app engine but on a local server. The error message is my obvious problem but i think specifically it may have something to do with the octet-stream I'm not sure. Any help would be appreciated!!! Thank you!

```css
var postString = "\(PHP_PATH)UploadTest.php"
        
        var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: postString)!)
        
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        
        var boundary = "---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"
        
        var contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)"
        
        request.addValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        
        println(request)
        
        var body = NSMutableData()
        
        body.appendData(("\r\n--\(boundary)\r\n" as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        
        body.appendData(("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"\(fileName)\"\r\n" as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        
        body.appendData(("Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        
        body.appendData(imageData)
        
        body.appendData(("\r\n--\(boundary)--\r\n" as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        
        request.HTTPBody = body
        
        var returnData = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil, error: nil)
        
        println(NSString(data: returnData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
```

Comment: Which part is not working? For example, in the first snippet the content-type is incorrect, and you're not posting any body.

Comment: The php part is not working. It does work when I'm using a webform to upload a file that way. But when i post from my iOS app I get those errors that say 'Content type not accepted by the url' Im not sure which content type it's expecting because like i said already it works if i go straight to the upload handler php page but since I'm using google cloud storage google forces me to use the special url to upload the image/video etc for security reasons.

Comment: Sorry Andrew it still not clear to me what you're trying to do. The code is snippet 1 surely doesn't work. What happens when you run the code in the dev appserver, do the logs provide any insight?

Comment: Ok I'm trying to upload an image or video from my iOS app to a storage bucket on google cloud storage.                                           In my php code snippet I'm posting the data to that specific php page from my iOS app.   Because app engine only allows 60 seconds to perform upload operations google recommends using their api to use a custom upload url instead of going the old way which is to upload from an app engine php url. In my iOS code the upload works if i don't store in google cloud storage bucket. But i need to store data there. check the link i provided.

Comment: What happens is when i use the stream context the result from the echo i call is the wrong content type. So how do i execute a url from a php page because in createuploadurl: after the url is executed it performs the upload handler.php which is what saves the data. I cannot use curl because google has disabled it in their php runtime so they recommend using the above approach. AGAIN ill say it worked with a webform perfectly because of how webforms can use urls as an action. How do i do this same action without using a webform?

Comment: Why are you not posting from your iOS app to the URL that is returned from CloudStorageTools::createUploadURL()? Here's an example using Java, you can do the same thing in PHP easy enough. https://medium.com/@purans/uploading-to-google-cloud-storage-from-ios-app-e9f4097b516

Comment: I see what it's doing. I though of that but i wanted to make sure there wasn't a way i could do it in one shot without making a second request. I think I'll try it that way since i know the url works. But if you think it could work in one single call that'd be a great answer too.